# Drop down list - display div when clicking an option

Tags: javascript, html

You must write a function that 'shows' the corresponding part of the form depending on what the user has selected. For example, if 'Pizza' is selected, the div #section2 with the question about Pizza type should be shown.

This is part of the html code

```
<form id="survey" action="#" method="post">

<div id="section1">
    <label for="food">What is your favourite type of food?</label>
    <select id="food" onchange="selection()">
        <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="mex">Mexican</option>
        <option value="thai">Thai</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    What is your favourite type of pizza?<br>
    <label for="hawaiian">Hawaiian</label><input type="radio" id="hawaiian">
    <label for="supreme">Supreme</label><input type="radio" id="supreme">
    <label for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</label><input type="radio" id="vegetarian">
</div>
```

How would i write a javascript function so that when I click the option pizza, it will display section 2? I'm a complete javascript novice so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/rQr6v/

JavaScript:

```
var sections = {
    'pizza': 'section2',
    'mex': 'section3',
    'thai': 'section4'   
};

var selection = function(select) {

    for(i in sections)
        document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = "none";    

    document.getElementById(sections[select.value]).style.display = "block";

}
```

Checkout the demo. Replace the `section3` and `section4` divs with actual content.

Comment: thank you very much, the demo is very good for seeing what the layout for the javascript and what the web document will look like.

Comment: i have one more question and was wondering if you could help me. i also need to display a message in the JavaScript console indicating which food type is selected. a hint given is to use console.log(""))

Comment: Add `console.log(select.value);` to the function.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of solutions for that. One of the simpliest options is to change your markup a bit and use `div` IDs.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="section1">
    <label for="food">What is your favourite type of food?</label>
    <select id="food" onchange="selection(this)">
        <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="mex">Mexican</option>
        <option value="thai">Thai</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section_pizza" style="display: none;">
    What is your favourite type of pizza?<br>
    <label for="hawaiian">Hawaiian</label><input type="radio" id="hawaiian">
    <label for="supreme">Supreme</label><input type="radio" id="supreme">
    <label for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</label><input type="radio" id="vegetarian">
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function selection(select) {
    document.getElementById("section_" + select.value).style.display = "block";
}
```

---

However, you can use [JQuery library](http://jquery.com/) and make it faster and more flexible. You can easily add animation to blocks and add extra functionality.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="section1">
    <label for="food">What is your favourite type of food?</label>
    <select id="food">
        <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="mex">Mexican</option>
        <option value="thai">Thai</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section2" data-type="pizza" style="display: none;">
    What is your favourite type of pizza?<br>
    <label for="hawaiian">Hawaiian</label><input type="radio" id="hawaiian">
    <label for="supreme">Supreme</label><input type="radio" id="supreme">
    <label for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</label><input type="radio" id="vegetarian">
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("#food").change(function() {
    $("[data-type]").hide();
    $("[data-type='" + this.value + "']").show(1000);
});
```

Comment: i can't really change that. this is a practical which i need to do :s. The id's need to stay section1,section2,section3 for the options pizza, mex and thai :/

Comment: @AnthonyDo Please check the post update and have a look at JQuery.

Comment: The OP did not ask for a jQuery solution. Your first JavaScript option didn't meet his needs. I up voted though.

Comment: You are not right. *I'm a complete javascript novice so any help would be great*. Hence I can give an advice to use JQuery, it is not prohibited. Moreover, first I gave quite workable solution -- in the question there is nothing mentioned about naming the blocks. This comes from the comment only. That's why I am confused.