# Is it possible to include HTML elements in a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Using a HTML `select` menu, I'm trying to create a dropdown list with HTML elements instead of plain text, but each element [isn't displaying properly inside the dropdown menu](http://jsbin.com/onexif/3/edit):

```
<select>
  <option value="1">
    <input type = "button" value = "This button won't display properly." />
  </option>
  <option value="">
    <b>Bold text won't display properly either.</b>
  </option>
</select>
```

Is there any syntactically valid method for embedding HTML elements inside a dropdown menu? If it isn't possible to do this using a `<select>` menu, then how can I create a dropdown widget that would allow nesting of HTML elements?

Comment: You'll need to pick a custom made `select` to do that

Comment: use li/ul tags and css

Comment: @Sebas I'm not sure how that would work. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Are there any custom-made `select`s that can do this?

Comment: You can use css to accomplish this. You just need to use the proper selection method. Also it depends on what kind of HTML you want.  In the past I needed to do images, so I created my own dropdown that works perfectly. If you want that code let me know.

Comment: @Cam Yes, I'm interested in seeing the code you used for this - perhaps you could post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: I think I found a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572004/drop-down-list-display-div-when-clicking-an-option

Comment: Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/mAz3c/

Comment: If you have questions let me know. This was created for a specific project but you can strip it real easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do it by building your own drop down handler.

CSS

```
.select {
    width: 10em;
    height: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.gradient1 {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ebebeb), to(#999999));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #999999);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #999999);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #999999);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #999999);
}
.gradient2 {
    background-color: #999999;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ebebeb), to(#ebebeb));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #ebebeb);
}
.list {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0% 0% 0% 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #888888;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -4px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.option {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
}
.option:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.arrowDown {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    left: 90%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #444;
}
.value {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="first" class="select">
        <div class="value"></div>
        <div class="arrowDown"></div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="option"><b>one</b></li>
            <li class="option"><strike>two</strike></li>
            <li class="option"><em>three</em></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="select">
        <div class="value"></div>
        <div class="arrowDown"></div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="option"><b>four</b></li>
            <li class="option"><strike>five</strike></li>
            <li class="option"><em>six</em></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="third" class="select">
        <div class="value"></div>
        <div class="arrowDown"></div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="option"><b>seven</b></li>
            <li class="option"><strike>eight</strike></li>
            <li class="option"><em>nine</em></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="getValue1">Get Text value 1</button>
    <button id="getValue2">Get HTML value 2</button>
    <button id="getValue3">Get Text value 3</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
(function (global) {
    global.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
        global.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);

        var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

        function getTextValue(selectId) {
            var select = document.getElementById(selectId),
                values,
                text = "";

            if (select) {
                values = select.getElementsByClassName("value");
                if (values && values.length) {
                    text = values[0].textContent;
                }
            }

            return text;
        }

        function getHTMLValue(selectId) {
            var select = document.getElementById(selectId),
                values,
                html = "";

            if (select) {
                values = select.getElementsByClassName("value");
                if (values && values.length) {
                    html = values[0].innerHTML;
                }
            }

            return html;
        }

        function hideAll(not) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function (select) {
                if (select !== not) {
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(select.getElementsByClassName("list"), function (ul) {
                        ul.style.display = "none";
                    });

                    select.className = (select.className.replace(/gradient[12]/, "").trim() + " gradient1").trim();
                }
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener("click", hideAll, false);

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function (select) {
            select.className = (select.className.trim() + " gradient1").trim();

            var lists = select.getElementsByClassName("list"),
                options,
                values,
                value;

            if (lists && lists.length) {
                options = lists[0].getElementsByClassName("option");
                if (options && options.length) {
                    values = select.getElementsByClassName("value");
                    if (values && values.length) {
                        value = values[0];
                        value.innerHTML = options[0].innerHTML;

                        Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function (option) {
                            option.addEventListener("click", function clickOption() {
                                value.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                            }, false);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            select.addEventListener("click", function clickSelect(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                hideAll(this)

                var lists = this.getElementsByClassName("list"),
                    list;

                if (lists && lists.length) {
                    list = lists[0];

                    if (global.getComputedStyle(list).display === "none") {
                        list.style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        list.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

                if (this.className.indexOf("gradient1") !== -1) {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("gradient1", "gradient2");
                } else {
                    this.className = (this.className.replace(/gradient\d/, "").trim() + " gradient1").trim();
                }
            }, false);
        });

        document.getElementById("getValue1").addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(getTextValue("first"));
        }, false);

        document.getElementById("getValue2").addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(getHTMLValue("second"));
        }, false);

        document.getElementById("getValue3").addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(getTextValue("third"));
        }, false);
    }, false);
}(window));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zUdja/)

Comment: This works very well, although it doesn't work when the elements are nested: http://jsfiddle.net/zUdja/75/ I hope that this problem can be fixed somehow.

Comment: I didn't write it with nesting in mind, it was purely an example of what would be the equivalent of HTML select/option elements, but with the ability to have markup as the values. I'm sure with some work it could be extended and turned into some kind of menu widget, but I'm certain that there are better menu widgets out there (nothing stopping you doing what you want with it though)

Answer (score 2):

> Q:-Is there any syntactically valid method for embedding HTML elements inside a dropdown menu

No. This is not possible any way semantically at this point. This is Invalid Html. You cannot have HTML tags inside option.

> Permitted content: Text with eventually escaped characters (like é).

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Foption)

You can take a look at some of the plugins or create a plugin yourself which will basically create a dropdown-widget with div's or some other tags out of the select option you provide.

Comment: I already realize that it's invalid HTML. I'm trying to find a syntactically valid way to embed HTML elements in a dropdown list.

Comment: There is no sytactical way at this point. You will have to create a widget. or use some plugins which creates dropdown widgets out of the select you provide.

Comment: @AndersonGreen That's exactly what the answer is saying: there *is no semantically valid way* to do this.

Comment: @Adrian It's probably not impossible to create a dropdown widget that allows HTML elements to be nested inside the dropdown list. There must be some way to do this - I just haven't found a working solution yet.

Comment: There may be any number of JavaScript-based drop-down-type widgets that do this, but the HTML `<select>`, which is *the* HTML drop-down, does not.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. If you want you can use CSS to create what you want. But it is not easy.

Comment: You can find an example at the search box at miniclip.com .

Comment: Do you know how to do this using CSS, by any chance?

Comment: No but I will try learn and if you want I will tell you tommorow.

Answer (score -1):

To include an option in a drop-down list, use the  tag in HTML. The HTML  tag is used within a form for defining options in the drop-down list.

You can try to run the following code to implement  element in HTML −

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML option Tag</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action = "/cgi-bin/dropdown.cgi" method = "post">
         <select name = "dropdown">
            <option value = "HTML" selected>HTML</option>
            <option value = "Aaron">Aaron</option>
         </select>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```