# How to put colorbar image inside select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, colorbar

I am developing an html page and I have to add a dropdown menu which allows me to select between two colorbars for a graph.

The dropdown options should visualise the colormaps, so I would like to place inside the dropdown options:

- an image of the colorbar
- or a gradient background color
- or something else that has the same color of the colorbar

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="input-group-text"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <select class="form-control" id="myDropdown">
      <option value="1">Colorbar1</option>
      <option value="2">Colorbar2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmtaezgo/

I have tried to specify the background in the css but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to represent the colorbars inside the dropdown options in some way via html or Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to render arbitrary html in your dropdown menu, which isn't possible with the vanilla `<select>` element.

The answers to this question ([Is it possible to include HTML elements in a dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490629/is-it-possible-to-include-html-elements-in-a-dropdown-list)) explore how you can build your own custom dropdown component which would allow you to render html for each option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).