# HTML in Spotfire and IronPython

Tags: html, ironpython, spotfire

I want to make a drop down list in spotfire using html. So based on choice selected I want to show custom divs. How to implement that ?? Can anyone help with the ironpython script

Comment: Please [clean up and improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). e.g. by adding a hyperlink to spotfire (its SDK/tools/documentation you are attempting to use) and explaining what you attempted to do so far.

Comment: I am using tibco spotfire

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use ironpython or do you want to use HTML? There is no need to use both although you could make a solution with both.

Anyway this question shows you how to do it with HTML and JavaScript, both of which I believe you can use in Spotfire.
[Drop down list - display div when clicking an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572004/drop-down-list-display-div-when-clicking-an-option)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create that script that is activated by your Property Control. The Property control would dynamically change a different textbox in the visualization. The code you would use would look a bit like this:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import HtmlTextArea

outputVis = output.As[HtmlTextArea]()

outputVis.HtmlContent = "<p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a new text area. Then, add a drop down list in this text area. You can create a new `Document.Properties` linked to this drop down list.
You can create many options in your drop down list, and your `Document.Properties` will have the selected value of your drop down list.

Text Area could be designed in HTML/CC so you can customize as you want.

Once you have your `Document.Properties` with the drop down list value, you can go on your chart properties and add a custom expression with your `Document.Properties` like `[MyCol]==$(docproperties)`

I hope it will help you !